# How to fix the deprecated Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper in Ember 1.13.9?

Tags: ember.js, deprecation-warning, htmlbars

I am currently upgrading from Ember 1.8.1 to Ember 1.13.9. My App is sort of oldschool by NOT using the ember-cli (no es6 whatever syntax).

How do i replace the deprecated Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper properly:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('date-ago',function(date) {
  return moment.utc(date).fromNow();
});
```

will advice you to

```
DEPRECATION: `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` is deprecated. 
Please refactor to use `Ember.Helpers.helper`. 
[deprecation id: ember-htmlbars.register-bound-helper]
```

So i thought replacing ´Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper´ with ´Ember.Helper.helper´ would do, but then these helpers are not available any more: "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'date-ago' could not be found!".

*How do I register a htmlbars helper in Ember 2.0 without ES6 syntax or ember-cli magic?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just assign it to Application:

```
App.FormatCurrencyHelper = Ember.Helper.helper(function(params, hash) {
  var cents = params[0];
  var currency = hash.currency;
  return currency + cents * 0.01;
});

//template
{{format-currency 75 currency="$"}}
```

[jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/xuxugodoca/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Awesome. Works! Good example - i like the parameter-value usage thing,

Comment: The registration of the helper via App.FormatCurrencyHelper = ...  was not in the docs. Before it was done somehow with registerHelper("format-currency", <helper>) and it worked. So thanks for pointing this out more clearly.